# What's the goal in the lighthouse puzzle (and how to achieve it)?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm stuck in this puzzle given by the cyclops at the lighthouse. What am I trying to accomplish here and how?

[image: barrel puzzle]

Comment: For those not wanting to just read a walkthrough: The aim is to powerup (#) the "? ?" tile.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So here's how it works:

- `V` blocks make a block in the direction of the V
- `T` block make a block above
- `<3` blocks power up all adjacent blocks
- `--->` blocks move the row below along one
- `|` blocks move the row to the left up one
- `#` indicates how many charges a block has

The first few clicks should be:

1. Click the V/T block, then expand out the chain of Vs to get the `--->`.
2. Make a T block by clicking the centre block
3. Move the T block along to be one block to the left underneath the ?? block
4. Click it, and expand to get a <3
5. Click the <3 to charge
6. Move it along one again and expand. You now have two adjacent <3 blocks to make an 'engine'

You can now expand out the rest of the area using the same method. You should end up with two `--->` blocks, and one `|`. You can use these blocks to move around the movement blocks so you can move an engine underneath the `??` block.

Power it up to win.

Comment: Got it - trial and error, but the answer was certainly helpful.

Comment: I can think of an easy way. A list of blocks to click on, in order.

Answer (score 26):

**The goal is to power up the [ ? ? ] block with a charge (#) and click it.** If you want to know exactly how to accomplish this, read on.

I made a video of myself completing the puzzle, you can see it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqwaxNLSeC8):

How to read the instructions:

- Letter-number combination tells you which block to click, check the image below to understand better. E3*6 means press E column, row 3, 6 times in a row.
- A charge is represented by **#**.
- To charge a block, you need two adjacent **<3** blocks.
- ***REMEMBER TO CHARGE ALL BLOCKS WHEN THEY PASS THE <3 BLOCKS!!!***

Here's the full description; step by step. Click blocks in the following order:

1. **D3 - D2 - E2 - D3 - E3 - E3 - F4 - F3 - E3 - G4 - G3 - G2**
2. Repeat F2 and F3 until the nearby blocks are fully charged and always when there is a block with low charges adjacent to one of them.
3. **D3 - E3*6 - C4 - C3 - C2 - E3 - E3 - A4 - A3 - A2 - A1 - C1**
4. Repeat C1 and B1 until the nearby blocks are fully charged and always when there is a block with low charges adjacent to one of them.
5. **E3 - B4 - B3 - B2 - A5 - B2 - B2 - B2 - B5 - E3 - B2 - E3 - B2 - E3 - B2 - A4 - E3*6 - B2*3**
6. **NOTE:** Video takes a longer route, here's the shortcut.
7. Charge both A1 and F2 with at least one charge.
8. **A1 - G2 - G1**
9. ***Done!***

[image: columns A-G, rows 1-6]

Answer (score 5):

I've made a close to minimal video showing the solution. It goes quickly, but doesn't have as many steps to follow. You can find it here [Lighthouse Puzzle Solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zV4dxRHXwcM)

Comment: Can you summarize your solution here, please?  That way, if the video ever goes down, your answer is still valid.